# Fetching and iterating over computer object from AD using Power Shell

Tags: c#, shell, powershell, active-directory

I have a query in Power shell which am executing from my c# code.

```
 public void RunPowerShell()
    {
        string command = "Get-ADComputer -Filter * " +
            "-Properties Displayname, CN, DNSHostName, DistinguishedName, lastLogon, Created, IPv4Address, lastLogonTimestamp, " +
            "OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemServicePack, OperatingSystemVersion, whenCreated, whenChanged, Enabled, PasswordLastSet, CanonicalName | Select-Object -first 10 | " +
            "select Displayname, CN, DNSHostName, DistinguishedName, lastLogon, Created, @{N='lastLogonTimestamp';" +
            " E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}, OperatingSystem " +
            " ,PasswordLastSet, CanonicalName ";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = RunScript(command);

    }


    private DataTable RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        var results = pipeline.Invoke();

        Logger.log("Got the results.");

        runspace.Close();

        DataTable ADdt = new DataTable();
        ADdt.Columns.Add("CN");
        ADdt.Columns.Add("DistinguishedName");
        ADdt.Columns.Add("OperatingSystem");
        ADdt.Columns.Add("lastLogonTimestamp");
        ADdt.Columns.Add("PasswordLastSet");

        int count = 0;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {

            label1.Text = (count++).ToString();

            ADdt.Rows.Add(new string[] { Convert.ToString(obj.Properties["CN"]), Convert.ToString(obj.Properties["DistinguishedName"]),
                   Convert.ToString(obj.Properties["OperatingSystem"]), Convert.ToString(obj.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"]),
                Convert.ToString(obj.Properties["PasswordLastSet"]) });

        }

        return ADdt;
    }
```

As per this code, I am getting all the computer object info in "results" variable. When trying to iterate over "result", it iterates only one time and all the computer object data is retrieved in "obj" iteration variable in first time.

I want to iterate over each returned computer object and retrieve different computer object properties and save it in a datatable to display.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: You could write a script that gets the information and serializes it into json or something then import it to your C#.

Comment: Also of note: you're using `Out-String`?  Your `var results` should be a `System.String` then.  `PSObject obj` doesn't look like it applies.

Comment: Instead of string can I get data as xml and then process it? how ?

Comment: [Export-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-5.1) or [ConvertTo-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just build a hash table inside your powershell script and return that?